# What is meant by a purely real number?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am a bit confused about this question:

[image]

I understand that a purely real complex number is where the 'a' value is 0,

But how would you go about solving this question? So after you multiply it by the conjugate, would you make it = 0? If so, why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your title makes it look like your question is about the notion of "purely real number", but in the question you say that you understand what it is and ask for a way to solve the problem. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Is $k$ meant to be real or complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u = \frac{k+4i}{1+ki}$$
We multiply the top and bottom of the fraction by the complex conjugate of the denominator, $(1-ki)$. This gives:
$$u = \frac{k+4i}{1+ki} \frac{1-ki}{1-ki} = \frac{k-k^2i +4i +4k}{1+k^2}$$
We want all the terms with an $i$ to cancel. So, that is the same as finding the $k$ value that makes $-k^2i +4i = 0$. These values are only $k = \pm 2$.

Comment: so you want the i's to cancel out for a purely real number?

Comment: @ChristopherU'ren Yes, since a number with no terms of $i$ is a purely real number

Answer (score 1):

In general complex number are in the form

$$z=x+iy$$

when $\Im(z)=y=0$ we have $z=x=\Re(z)$ and we talk of *purely real* number.

In other words in the complex plane $z$ lies on the $x$ axis.

Similarly when $x=0$ we have $z=y=\Im(z)$ and we talk of *purely imaginary* number.

[image]

In that case the condition is equivalent to

$$u=\bar u \iff \frac{k+4i}{1+ki}=\frac{k-4i}{1-ki}$$

that is

$$(k+4i)(1-ki)=(k-4i)(1+ki)$$

$$k-k^2i+4i+4k=k+k^2i-4i+4k$$

$$2k^2i=8i \iff k^2=4 \iff k=\pm 2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write
$$\dfrac{k+4i}{1+ki}\times\dfrac{1-ki}{1-ki}$$

Comment: Nosrati.Simply nice:)

Comment: @PeterSzilas thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $k$ is a real  number ,$\frac {k+4i} { 1+ki}=\frac {(k+4i)(1-ki)} {(1+ki)(1-ki)}=\frac {4+4k+4i-k^{2}i} {1+k^{2}}$ so the imaginary part is $0$ iff $k^{2}=4$ or $k =\pm 2$. ,

Comment: but why is the imaginary part = 0?

Comment: A complex number is purely real iff the imaginary part is $0$.

Comment: isn't a complex number purely real when the real part is 0? thanks

Comment: @ChristopherU'ren The imaginary part is the part that is a multiple of $i$. Thus, if you can get all the $i$'s to cancel, you have no imaginary part left and thus have a fully real number.

Comment: If the real part is $0$ you get a purely imaginary number.

Answer (score 0):

A complex number $u=a+bi$ will be a purely real number if $b=0$. Then:
$$u = \frac{k+4i}{1+ki}=a \iff k+4i=a+aki \iff (a-k)+(4-ak)i=0 \iff \\
\begin{cases}a-k=0 \\ 4-ak=0\end{cases} \iff 4-k^2=0 \iff k=\pm 2. $$